# Error Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister and Could not locate getter method for property

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have checked my pojo classes but I am unable to find the error. Can anyone please help. Below are the classes and the mapping and config files.

I am trying to have a one-many relationship between the patent and inventor. the below error pops up frequently. I am unable to resolve it this time.

```
public class Inventor {

private int id;
private String inventor;
private Patent pat;

    public Inventor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getInventor() {
        return inventor;
    }
    public Patent getPat() {
        return pat;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setInventor(String inventor) {
        this.inventor = inventor;
    }
    public void setPat(Patent pat) {
        this.pat = pat;
    }
    public Inventor(String inventor, Patent pat) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.inventor=inventor;
        this.pat=pat;
    }
    public Inventor(int id,String inventor, Patent pat) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id=id;
        this.inventor=inventor;
        this.pat=pat;
    }
public class Patent  {

private int id;
private String application_doc_num;
private String application_date;
private String application_country;
private String publication_doc_num;
private String publication_date;
private String publication_country;
private String publication_kind;
private String patent_no;
private String Assignee;
private String Examiner;
private String Agent;
private String Doc_identifier;
private Set<Inventor> inventors=new HashSet<Inventor>();

public Set<Inventor> getInventors() {
    return inventors;
}
public void setInventors(Set<Inventor> inventors) {
    this.inventors = inventors;
}
public Patent(int id, String Doc_identifier,String publication_date) {

    this.id=id;
    this.Doc_identifier=Doc_identifier;
    this.publication_date=publication_date;

}
public void setPatent_no(String patent_no) {
    this.patent_no = patent_no;
}
public void setPublication_country(String publication_country) {
    this.publication_country = publication_country;
}
public void setPublication_date(String publication_date) {
    this.publication_date = publication_date;
}
public void setPublication_doc_num(String publication_doc_num) {
    this.publication_doc_num = publication_doc_num;
}
public void setApplication_country(String application_country) {
    this.application_country = application_country;
}
public void setApplication_date(String application_date) {
    this.application_date = application_date;
}
public void setApplication_doc_num(String application_doc_num) {
    this.application_doc_num = application_doc_num;
}
public String getPatent_no() {
    return patent_no;
}
public String getPublication_country() {
    return publication_country;
}
public String getPublication_date() {
    return publication_date;
}
public String getPublication_doc_num() {
    return publication_doc_num;
}
public String getApplication_country() {
    return application_country;
}
public String getApplication_date() {
    return application_date;
}
public String getApplication_doc_num() {
    return application_doc_num;
}
public Patent( String Doc_identifier,String publication_date) {

    this.Doc_identifier=Doc_identifier;
    this.publication_date=publication_date; 
}

public Patent() {

}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDoc_identifier() {
    return Doc_identifier;
}
public void setDoc_identifier(String doc_identifier) {
    Doc_identifier = doc_identifier;
}
public String getPublication_kind() {
    return publication_kind;
}
public void setPublication_kind(String publication_kind) {
    this.publication_kind = publication_kind;
}

public String getAgent() {
    return Agent;
}
public String getExaminer() {
    return Examiner;
}
public void setAgent(String agent) {
    Agent = agent;
}
public void setExaminer(String examiner) {
    Examiner = examiner;
}
public String getAssignee() {
    return Assignee;
}
public void setAssignee(String assignee) {
    Assignee = assignee;
}
}

    **Config file**

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  </property>

  <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
  system
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
  ****
  </property>

  <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="Patent.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="Inventor.hbm.xml"/>


   </session-factory> 
  </hibernate-configuration>

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

    **Mapping files**

    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.stax.Patent" table="system.PATENT">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains the patent detail. 
     </meta>
     <id name="id" type="int" column="pat_id">
     <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <set name="inventors" inverse="true" cascade="all">
     <key column="inv_pat_id" />
     <one-to-many class="com.stax.Inventor"/>
     </set>
     <property name="Doc_identifier" column="pat_doc_identifier"             type="string"/>
   <property name="publication_date" column="pat_date" type="string"/>
     </class>
     </hibernate-mapping>

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
     <hibernate-mapping >
     <class name="com.stax.Inventor" table="system.INVENTOR">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains the inventor records. 
     </meta>
    <id name="id" column="inv_id" type="int">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="inventor" column="inv_inventor" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="patent" class="com.stax.Inventor"
        column="inv_pat_id" />
     </class> 
    </hibernate-mapping>
```